# how can find Form Validations in JavaScript not work

Tags: javascript

```html
<script>
  function validate() {
    var username = document.getElememtById("uname");
    var password = document.getElememtById("pass");

    if (username.value == "" || password.value == "") {
      alert("no data");
    }
  }
</script>


<form>
  <input id="uname" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>

  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>

  <button onclick="validate()" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is "find Form Validations" ?

Comment: You want to prevent form submission if `uname` or `password` is empty?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("uname");` not `document.getElememtById("uname");`

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default behavior using `e.preventDefault` and also there is typo in `getElememtById`

```js
function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var username = document.getElementById("uname");
  var password = document.getElementById("pass");

  if (username.value == "" || password.value == "") {
    alert("no data");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="uname" type="text" placeholder="username" />

  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password" />

  <button button type='submit' onclick="validate(event)" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in *getElememtById*, should be *getElementById*. You also have to prevent the default event if condition is *true*.

**Please Note:** *input* is called empty or void element and only have a start tag since they can't have any content. Using closing tag in empty element is a bad parctice.

```html
<script>
  function validate(e) {
    use 
    var username = document.getElementById("uname");
    var password = document.getElementById("pass");

    if (username.value == "" || password.value == "") {
      alert("no data");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
</script>


<form>
  <input id="uname" type="text" placeholder="username"/>

  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password"/>

  <button onclick="validate(event)" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues on your code:

**1)** The input tag do not use a close tag like `</input>`

**2)** You need to pass `event` as the argument of your custom function and then call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default submit event associated with the `form`.

**3)** `getElememtById()` is actually named like `getElementById()`

## Working example:

```js
function validate(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById("uname");
    var password = document.getElementById("pass");
    
    if (username.value == "" || password.value == "")
    {
        alert("no data");
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="uname" type="text" placeholder="username">
  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password">
  <button onclick="validate(event)" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```